# jq program to manipulate objects with unknown keys

Tags: json, jq

I need to manipulate objects in an array where the single key of those objects is not a fixed, common string. Here is a real quick example:

```
echo '{ "a": { "b" : 1 } }'|jq '. as $save|keys'
```

So, the problem is "a" could be anything. So, I cannot use jq '.a'. The only way I have found to get the key name is via the *keys* built-in function. However, it seems that keys does not want to play along with a comma (throws syntax error, like:)

```
echo '{ "a": { "b" : 1 } }'|jq 'keys, . as $save|$save[.]'
```

and if you reverse them as the only pipe stage, you get another error:

```
echo '{ "a": { "b" : 1 } }'|jq '. as $save, keys'
jq: error: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting 
'|' (Unix shell quoting issues?) at <top-level>, 
line 1:  . as $save, keys
jq: 1 compile error
```

It seems that keys expects to be the only operator on the input and only source of output.

Is there any other way to *find* "a"?

In the event that I have over-simplified the example I gave and you don't understand the problem, then please consider a subset of the data I actually need to manipulate:

```
{
  "rows": [
    {
      "i-0cf0": {
        "chef_environment": "alpha-prod",
        "ec2.placement_availability_zone": "us-east-1d"
      }
    },
    {
      "i-f9aa": {
        "chef_environment": "alpha-qa",
        "ec2.placement_availability_zone": "us-east-1b"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comments have led me to add this additional content. An example of additional manipulations I want to do for the above input, is: select based on particular values of chef_environment and for those, output the key and availability zone, e.g.

```
i-f9aa,us-east-1b
```

Comment: What's your *real* goal? That is, what's your intended output, that "finding" `a` is a step towards? You're showing us your real data, but not what kind of manipulations you want to do with it -- for most queries I'd anticipate wanting to do on that data, I wouldn't need to "find" the key names at all, but could just skip straight to the values (unless extracting a list of key names as output is the goal of your jq script).

Comment: For example, `.rows[][].chef_environment` will list `alpha-prod` and `alpha-qa` as your outputs, without ever having needed to list the key names -- see this running at https://jqplay.org/s/h44SdHe0f9

Comment: For another example where the keys *are* part of your output, see https://jqplay.org/s/29aRq4q7BX

Comment: ...anyhow, without a description of the specific manipulation you want to accomplish, this question is too broad to be answerable. (The problem with showing us code that doesn't work, and not showing us the output you want that code to have, is that we can't necessarily guess your intent from a piece of broken code any more than the compiler can).

Comment: So... the goal is to obtain a list of the keys in those objects? [`.rows[] | keys[]`](https://jqplay.org/s/VGIvKMdrPd)

Comment: @CharlesDuffy - thanks for the comments. I added an example of the manipulation. Actually data is more extensive, so it is just scratching the surface of what I want to be able to do.

Comment: @JeffMercado - thanks for the thought. I said that is not what I needed.

Comment: That looks pretty much *exactly* like my second jqplay link (just using commas instead of tabs).

Comment: "It seems that keys expects to be the only operator on the input and only source of output." No it doesn't, you just have to use correct syntax. You started out doing that, and then invented something new that isn't correct. Using `|` after an `as` variable assignment is admittedly strange, but correct. If you kept along that path your original code *could* have worked (although `to_entries` makes it easier).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The jq function `to_entries` will transform `{ "KEY": "VALUE" }` to `{ "key": "KEY", "value": "VALUE" }`.

Given that, you can refer directly to the keys, or to the values they're mapped to, as so:

```
.rows[] | to_entries[] |  [.key, .value["ec2.placement_availability_zone"]] | @csv
```

...given your input, outputs (when run in raw mode):

```
"i-0cf0","us-east-1d"
"i-f9aa","us-east-1b"
```